# Docusign Jar conflict with Jersey

Tags: java

I have the code works fine but when using the same code (jars and dependencies) in a servlet it doesn't work, it gets to first line: `ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();`

```
                 ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
                 apiClient.setBasePath(BaseUrl);

                 // create JSON formatted auth header
                 String creds = "{\"Username\":\"" +  UserName + "\",\"Password\":\"" +  Password + "\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"" +  IntegratorKey + "\"}";
```

then I get the **error**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.LocaleProvider to com.sun.jersey.spi.HeaderDelegateProvider
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3369)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.osgi.OsgiRegistry$OsgiServiceFinder$1.next(OsgiRegistry.java:147)
```

I am trying to use `ClassLoader` but I can't make it to work

I am using these jars

```
@docusign-esign-java-2.6.0.jar,\
@jersey-client-1.19.1.jar,\
@jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar,\
@jackson-core-2.9.5.jar,\
@jackson-datatype-joda-2.1.5.jar,\
@joda-time-2.9.3.jar,\
@jersey-multipart-1.19.1.jar,\
@jersey-core-1.19.1.jar,\
@jackson-annotations-2.9.5.jar,\
@jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.9.5.jar,\
@jackson-jaxrs-base-2.9.5.jar
```